# Unable to link FaceBook account to High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, password, facebook, authentication

I'm using a late 2009 MacBook (A1342) running a clean install of High Sierra.

When I add my FaceBook account in system preferences, it seems to be successful but macOS continues to prompt me for the password even though it is correct. Upon visiting the FaceBook website, I see notifications for signins to verify. Each time, I confirm "this was me" and to add that sign in to the list of trusted signins. However, I continue to receive that same notification with each signin attempt.

Does anyone know how to fix this?